# how to save only the output of the llm in langchain memory

Tags: nlp, langchain, large-language-model

i am going to analyze of bunch of documents to analyze the credit worthness of a company so due to context length i am going to feed them one by one and create a summary memory .

```
template = """You are a senior financial analyst a conversation with a human.
{context}
{chat_history}
Human: {human_input}
senior financial analyst:"""

prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["chat_history", "human_input", "context"], template=template
)
memory=ConversationSummaryBufferMemory(llm=summarizer,memory_key="chat_history", max_token_limit=10000,input_key="human_input")
chain = load_qa_chain(
    llm, chain_type="stuff", memory=memory, prompt=prompt,verbose=True
)
```

```
  query="analyze this company s credit worthness based on the above information credit worthness"
  for doc in docs:
    output=chain({"input_documents": doc, "human_input": query})
```

in the summary memory i want to just store the the output of my llm not my query every time